# Comparing two adjacent cells

Tags: excel

```
**A1      B1      Comparison**
a,b,c    a,b,c       Equal

b,c,d    d,e,f     Not equal

b,a,c    a,b,c       Equal

e,f,g    e,f,g       Equal
```

How to do this?
If the letters(separated by comma) in the cell are not in the proper order, then also it will show equal if bolth the adjacent cells have the same letters.

Comment: The answer I will give is that you should not be working with data in un-normalized CSV form.  It would be much easier if you had each letter in a separate cell.

Comment: You could read in the data as CSV into Excel, which would place each letter in its own cell, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If the first 3 values are in cell **A1** and the one for comparison are in cell **B1**.

Paste the following formula to cell **C1**:

```
=AND(IFERROR(FIND(MID(A1,1,1),B1)>0,FALSE),IFERROR(FIND(MID(A1,3,1),B1)>0,FALSE),IFERROR(FIND(MID(A1,5,1),B1)>0,FALSE))
```

That will work well.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: a,b a,b,c TRUE        ----> This is coming TRUE. But I want this as FALSE.

Comment: What is the meaning of MID(A1,1,1), MID(A1,3,1), MID(A1,5,1)?           Why are we not using MID(A1,2,1), MID(A1,4,1)?

Comment: Sorry thought you are comparing only 3 to 3.